# Firebase get the value of the data Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
String userID = user.getUid();
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

I have userId of the user so when I'm opening my app for the 2nd time(after signing in) I should not show the select user type layout. So  I ve to check whether the use is Customer or Staff  internally. So the problem is I ve to check the User Id is there . I couldn't find any method to get whether user Id is there or not! There is method called addListenerForSingleValueEvent but that won't help me in my scenario. Pic of the database is given here

[image]

I don't know how to continue after this

```
mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child("Customers")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if an user exists in a particular section of your Firebase database, first you need to add a listener and then use `exists()` method directly on the `dataSnapshot` object. So, asumming that `Users` node is a direct child of the Firebase-database root, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference customersRef = rootRef.child("Users").child("Customers").child(userID);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //do somethig
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
customersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: It's just listening ! It takes little bit time too. Can't we directly query without any listeners or like the method we set the values !??

Comment: No, you cannot query directly as you say. When it comes to Firebase, everything it's about listeners. So in order to retrive some data, you need to add a listener. When you set a value, you only need to use `setValue()` method directly on reference. For retrieving data you need to attach a listener.